# How to show image from webcam

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject, webcam-capture

I never needed to work with camera before, so I do not know where to start.
I need to display the image of a real-time camera, to capture and save to a file.
I'm using python3 and gtk3.

Does gtk has any feature for this?

Comment: I've used opencv in the past

Comment: OpenCV? WoW!
Something simpler?

Comment: That's the only tool I've ever used that I'm aware of and can read from the webcam. It's [pretty straightforward](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#capture-video-from-camera)

Comment: What about pyQT? OpenCV is currently only python2 which is not what OP wants (assuming from the tags)

Comment: OpenCV is available for Python3... And isn't that hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the image from a webcam is to use OpenCV. It allows you to get the image with just 2 lines of code and 2 more to show it, like so:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = cap.read()

cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But there is a downside, namely that OpenCV for Python 3 has to be build from source. Most people don't like building from source so they say it is not available.

Luckily there is the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages by Gohlke (University of California)](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) which also offers a precompiled version of OpenCV for Python 3. Installing that using `pip` should be easy.

Comment: In another forum someone suggested gstreamer. Which is the best?

Comment: I personally prefer OpenCV because it just gives you frames and you can decide what to do with it. My experience with GStreamer is that it is more complex but sometimes more powerful. I guess it just really depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: What is encouraging to use gstreamer is that it is based on gobjects. And since I'm using GTK +, the integration would be simpler. I guess. But he seems to be really difficult.

Comment: Yeah if it was as simple as adding a widget I would have recommend GStreamer, but saddly it is not that easy. So the next best thing is OpenCV.